# Migrate bcrypt password hash from PHP to Python - ValueError: Invalid hashed_password salt

Tags: php, python, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I have a PHP7 app which hashes users passwords like this

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

For example, if I pass `test1234` to that, I've got:

```
$2y$10$aazE9OUKZlOQiM6axwxU/utpOURLQ58pluqtFZkkGE3R9ShtUxBOm
```

Now, I have a Python app, which has to update users passwords too. It uses something like this:

```
import bcrypt

hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

As an example, the same password `test1234` hashed as:

```
$2a$12$vsI9Vf9gWj/Au3McYradxuozyZychmlfqoCJcSacDWuMzUDVpv33m
```

As you can see, PHP generated `$2y` where Python did `$2a` - so they are a bit different versions of hashes.

Now, if I will try to verify, both Python and PHP hashes, in PHP like this:

```
$result = password_verify($password, $hash);
```

I have `true` in both cases. But, if I try to verify both on Python side:

```
bcrypt.checkpw(password, hash)
```

It only works for when I pass hash generated in Python. If I pass hash generated in PHP, I've got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid hashed_password salt
```

My question: is there anything I'm missing?

The `bcrypt` module is supplied by the `py-bcrypt` project, version 0.4, that I had installed using pip:

```
pip3 install py-bcrypt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`2y` and `2a` are [two different versions of the bcrypt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history). As Wikipedia states, `2y` is *specific to PHP only*:

> In June 2011, a bug was discovered in `crypt_blowfish`, a PHP implementation of BCrypt. *[...]*
>   They also suggested the idea of having crypt_blowfish emit `$2y$` for hashes generated by the fixed algorithm.
>
> Nobody else, including canonical OpenBSD, adopted the idea of 2x/2y. This version marker change was limited to `crypt_blowfish`.

The `py-bcrypt` module is behind the times here, as it only supports the `2a` version! As of February 2014, version 2b is the current release (a bug hashing passwords longer than 255 characters was fixed). The current 0.4 release was made in 2013, so I'd consider the project dead at this point.

Instead, you should install the [`bcrypt` project](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/). While it only supports `2a` and `2b` to *generate* hashes, it explicitly [supports normalising `2y` hashes to treat them as `2b` hashes](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/commit/c95966955b60a446e9d23af0b9500fbc5e43c0cc), and so I had no problems verifying the `2y` hash using that project:

```
>>> import bcrypt
>>> bcrypt.__version__
'3.1.4'
>>> hash = b'$2y$10$aazE9OUKZlOQiM6axwxU/utpOURLQ58pluqtFZkkGE3R9ShtUxBOm'
>>> bcrypt.checkpw(b'test1234', b'$2y$10$aazE9OUKZlOQiM6axwxU/utpOURLQ58pluqtFZkkGE3R9ShtUxBOm')
True
```